# Finding my Bitcoin and my wallet

Tags: wallet

How do I recover my lost Bitcoin wallet I have had in the past that I know have collected Bitcoin but I don't know how to access them

Comment: What do you have to recover it from? What do you know?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how lost it is. If your OS crashed, boot it into recovery mode, decrypt the key (if necessary) and then copy back. Otherwise, it could be harder if not impossible.